# Didn't updating class for element - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

After blur, if input is empty, i want to add class .hass-error, after that i write some text into input, on idea class .hass-error must removed and added class has-success. .has-error is removing but new clas

```
function checkSignupData() {
      var username = $('.signup-panel input[name="username"]');

        username.on({
          'focusin': function(){},
          'focusout': function(){
            if(!this.value.length) {
              $(this).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').toggleClass('has-error');
            }
            else if(this.value.length > 3 && this.value.length < 32) {
              $(this).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').toggleClass('has-success');
            }
          }
        });
    }
    setInterval(checkSignupData(), 100);
```

Comment: why not just use addClass()?

Comment: Vohuman, it doesn't matter

Comment: What exactly doesn't matter? Having an interval? The code actually doesn't create any intervals and if you fix it you will have many event handlers for the same elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function checkSignupData() {
   var username = $('.signup-panel input[name="username"]');

   if (username.text().length > 0) {  
       username.closest('.form-group').removeClass().addClass('has-success');
   } else {
       username.closest('.form-group').removeClass().addClass('has-error');
   }
}

window.setInterval(function(){
    checkSignupData();
}, 5000);
```

This is not an ideal solution using `setInterval` as the DOM will become messy and slow your application. For example, if this `username` is within a form, then you can call the check when the form is submitted. Like I said, not the most ideal solution but the one I think you are trying to achieve.

`checkSignupData()` will be called every 5 seconds.

Another solution I have just thought of which may work:

```
username.on('keyup', function() {
    // call function
});
```

I originally thought this may not work as it would not fire if nothing was in the `input`. However, pressing a backspace to remove text will trigger the event as well. The only think is that on start up, you will have to initialise the element to have `has-error` class as there will be initially nothing in it.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need set interval because you are using events you will end up binding tons of event handlers which is probably causing your problem

also you should use addClass as it's more assertive

edit: remove the setInterval and call checkSignupData one time

Comment: also I'm not positive focusin and out are events, might need focus and blur, respectively